# Unable to scrape Javascript website - API Calls / XHR request

Tags: javascript, python, json, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I am unable to scrape a Java script dependent website. I need to obtain list of schools from the API call that sends to the server using XHR request which gets the JSON object

I am using the same Request headers that go with the XHR request including the cookie value. Not sure why it isn't working. It gives timeout error basically. Attaching the Python code and screenshot from google chrome request header (Network tab) and error from vs code termial :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json

class SchoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'school'
    # allowed_domains = ['www.directory.ntschools.net']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.directory.ntschools.net/api/System/GetAllSchools/']

    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'BIGipServerdirectory.ntschools.net_443.app~directory.ntschools.net_443_pool=360972810.20480.0000',
    'Host': 'directory.ntschools.net',
    'Referer': 'https://directory.ntschools.net/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'}


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.directory.ntschools.net/api/System/GetAllSchools/',headers= self.headers,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(json.loads(response.body))
```

[image: XHR Request]

[image: Request Headers]

[image: Error code from VS Code terminal]

Answer (score 0):

I guess i know now what i did wrong. I was using wrong api url with 'www' in it while the original url doesnt have it. My Bad. Thanks to those who did invest their time on this. Cheers